# how to write comment in correct way

Tags: html, validation, xhtml

How to write comments in an (x)HTML file? just using `<!-- comment -->`?
Is it correct also?: `<!-"-" comment "-"->`?
Any other methods to put a comment in code? (because some editors filter `<!-- -->` comments).

Comment: It seems the question really is, "How do I add a comment to my HTML in editors that filter the `<!-- -->` syntax?" @Kikio, which editors are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the correct and **only** way for HTML and XML:

```
<!-- comment -->
```

Your other example is **not** valid.

Comment: thanks, do you have any ideas about other ways to write comment? for example, use css and javascript comments.

Comment: kikio- what do you mean "other ways to write comment"? css and javascript use a different method for writing comments, which you can't use in an (x)HTML file.

Comment: @kikio - HTML comments are HTML comments. Javascript has its own way to comment and CSS yet another. Comments are part of the language/markup specification, they are not universally the same across them.

Answer (score 2):

The only valid type of (x)HTML comment is `<!-- -->`.